# Show one position of ng-repeat and reload a dropdown each time

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, I'm actually new to angularJS and I've been searching for a while and trying different ways to achieve something, but it seems impossible, to me.

I have this ng-repeat that should show only one of my 6 position array. When I click in "Change", than I should load the second and then the third and so on, until all my data have been accessed and changed by the user, that's why I limited it to 1.

The Professor's select should load according to a parameter from the current ng-repeat class. I have no idea how to solve this problem. I'm trying right now to use a service to load the professor's dropdown, but with no success.

```
<div class="row" **ng-repeat="class in classes | offset:currentPage | limitTo: 1"** on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
    <div style="display: block;">
        <div>
            <p><label for="">Change:</label> {{ class.professorName }}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p><label for="">By:</label>
             <select id="professor" name="professor" class="form-control">
                <option ng-repeat="professor in professors" value="{{professor.id}}">{{ professor.name }}</option>
             </select>
          </p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
    <hr>
    <center><button type="button" ng-click="change(class.classId)" class="btn btn-primary">Change</button></center>
</div>
```

What's the best way to achieve something like this (Show only one item each time and after user submits the form, go to the next position... and for each ng-repeat item, I have to reload the professors dropdown)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding you correctly, you want

ng-repeat class in classes //limit 1 //index i.e. [0] +1 change index after button click so you move to the next class index location?

If your setting a value of professor.id in the class or a property that isn't set or is null/undefined before the button, then just add this to your parent div with the loop of class in classes.

```
ng-if="!class.propName" //if property/dropdown not set
```

If this isn't what your looking for please expand on your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Samuel! The first problem I have to solve is to populate the professors SELECT by calling an ajax function with a $scope.class.id, to get all professors of the specific class. I tried to implement a Service for that, but it's not possible to use $scope.class (as a result of nr-repeat="class in classes") inside my controller, to pass the id as a parameter to my service.

Comment: Hmm, what about doing professor in ajaxfunc(class.id) that might be what your looking for then.

Comment: Also, FYI you might be dealing with it being a isolate scope so if you do ng-init obj={} then obj.class or obj.func is avail in child scope or pass through your controller as a arg

Comment: Thanks Samuel, finally it worked. I used $q and promise and now my professors SELECT is ok. Now, I'll try the next step, which is record and go to the next position of my array. Thank you!